# How to get the html contents of millions urls links

Tags: multithreading, web-crawler

Given a url link, I want to get the contents of the page in html format .In Java,I know that I can implement this with `getInputStream` method.

Question is that, now I have millions of URLs. And want to get the html pages of them. If I still use the `getInputStream`. It is time-consuming and the performance is bad.  So I want to speed up the fetch page process.

Hope to get efficient method and high speed to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `getInputStream` only gives us a tiny window into your code and has nothing to do with your performance problems.  Can you show what classes and methods you are using to download the page?  You using apache http client, or Java URL, or ???

Comment: @Gray I use http client and the method is just Get.But I am not familiar with http network programing.I wanna get a better way to download the webpage. Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the related items or do a search on Web Crawling. For your perfomance issue this links looks interessting: http://www.andreas-hess.info/programming/webcrawler/index.html  Basicly it uses queues in conjunction with multiple Threads to speed up the crawling.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks,I'll take a look at the webcrawler.

Answer (score 1):

Massive spidering of a million URLs is a tricky business.  On one hand it is easy to use a thread pool (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)`) and a pool of [Apache Http Clients](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).  However, even a medium speed system running this code can completely do a denial of service attach on a server -- sending so many requests to a particular server that start to fall over.

The trick is how to throttle your threads so they don't make requests to the same server (maybe even the same class-C) at such a rate to overwhelm them.  One way to do it is to have one thread do the name -> IP resolution so then it can add URLs to the to-be-spidered queue in a measured way.  Google, for example, spiders small sites an URL a minute.  They are down to a second which shows how good their spider technology is at scheduling downloads.  But there is some medium hard thread and queue logic there to get it right.

I think the best way to do this is to use existing technology that [hopefully] has already solved this issues.  Here are some links that might lead you to an existing implementation.

- @Andreas mentioned a [threaded web crawler project](http://www.andreas-hess.info/programming/webcrawler/index.html) and I'm sure there are others out there.
- This is a sun project to [write a web crawler](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ThirdParty/WebCrawler/)
- Here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495289/what-is-a-good-java-web-crawler-library

Comment: I am appreciated of this answer. I think The [web4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) will do me a favor. Actually I just want to download the page of a URL link and then parse the html tags. But the number of URLs is very large.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using some open-source web crawler such as [Crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) or [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/). Just import all your urls as seeds of the crawler and set the depth=1.

Crawler4j is a light-weight web crawler providing very simple interface for users. It is very easy to integrate Crawler4j with your applications.

Compared with Crawler4j, Nutch is much complex. It will take more time to learn and customize nutch.
If you want to grab it by yourself, Apache HTTP Client is a good choice. Many web crawlers are based on it. To be polite, restraint number of your requests in a second and that help you avoid the  denial of service issue.

Comment: @John Rene, I can not find your email address in your profile. And I think you didn't see my comment on the other question. I'm studying nutch for a while and glad to have a chance to share our ideas with each other.